# Retirar "openfiledialog" dos Campo C#

Tags: c#

Boas,

Tenho um OpenFileDialog no meu programa, mas não queria que quando "abro" apareça o que está na imagem...
Se eu fechar a janela, fica "openfiledialog" na Textbox, e quero que fique em branco, visto que não foi nada seleccionado.

**Imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Request File (*.CSR)|*.csr|Configuration File (*.CNF)|*.cnf";
        DialogResult resposta = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (resposta == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string arquivo = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            VariaveisGlobais.cnf = arquivo;
            VariaveisGlobais.csr = label2.Text;
        }

        textBox3.Text = string.Format("{0}", openFileDialog1.FileName);
        label2.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        button2.Enabled = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName) == ".cnf";
        button3.Enabled = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName) == ".csr";
        button4.Enabled = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName) == ".csr";
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na sua instância do `OpenFileDialog`, antes de chamar o método `ShowDialog()`, use da propriedade `FileName` para colocar o nome de um arquivo proposto:

```
openFileDialogInstance.FileName = "arquivo.txt";
```

Caso o nome deste arquivo seja um pouco extenso, o cursor vai ficar no final do nome do arquivo, podendo cortar o nome na exibição.

Se isso acontecer, use da propriedade `ShowHelp` para deixar o nome do arquivo selecionado:

```
openFileDialogInstace.ShowHelp = true;
```